# Old Application crashs when clicking on File Open, File Save or File SaveAs

Tags: windows-7

I have a 10 year old application which was used in Windows XP.  This application is closed source so I am not able to fix it by using the source code.  Now, I want to use it in Windows 7.

Most of the functionality of the application is working well except for the `File Save`, `File SaveAs` and `File Open` dialogs.

Clicking on one of these buttons in the toolbar or in the menu bar crashes the application.

I have attached Visual Studio Debugger and got the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at {Address} in {Assembly}: 0xc0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x00000000
```

I assume that the problem is as described [**here**](http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.de/2007/10/vc-60-getting-0xc0000005-access.html).

Is it possible to fix this issue by replacing the DLL's / using Shim/Hooking the Open/Save Dialog or using a Manifest file?

**Edit**

We are not allowed to use the Windows XP mode.

Comment: If you have Windows 7 Professional, Ultimate, Enterprise, you can Install and run that program in XP mode, see if it works....http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode

Comment: Thanks but it is not allowed to use the XP mode.

Comment: Did you try running the program in compatibility mode?....http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-windows

Comment: @Moab I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work.

Comment: you will need to run XP in a virtual machine then...https://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 0):

Look for the folder where the program is installed. Odds are, this folder is *read-only* for standard users. In Windows XP, programs often got away with writing here anyway because just about everyone ran as an administrator by default. In Windows Vista and later this is often no longer the case. Try setting the permissions on the folder to give Modify access for the Users group. Also look for the default location that the program wants to use for it's Open/Save dialog and do the same thing.